# Transforme $y'=-2x+2xy^2$ in an ODE of second oreder.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Cauchy problem

$$(C):\begin{cases}y'=-2x+2xy^2\\ y(0)=\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$

1) Let $f$ a solution of $(C)$. Write an ODE of second order such that $f$ is solution.

2) Write the taylor expansion at second order of $f$.

**My attempt**

1) I have no idea how to do. I tried do a substitution like $z=1-y^2$ or $z=y^2$, but nothing. After, I was thinking that if$$f'=-2x+2xf^2$$ then $$f''=-2+2f^2+4xff'$$
which is on ODE of second order, but same as before, I didn't find an easy substitution that take of the term $f^2$. Any idea ?

**I insist on the fact that I'm not looking for solving the ODE, I'm only looking for the answer of 1)**. Indeed, to solve it it's easy since $$(C)\iff \frac{y'}{(1-y)(1+y)}=2x$$
an thus, we can simply do a decomposition to conclude.

2) I think it's a consequence of the 1).

Comment: Would it help if you first solve for $y$?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see your point now.

Comment: @Math-fun: No problem :-) Moreover, you can't solve directly the homogeneous equation since it's not linear (if it was your first suggest :-)) But may be it's not what you wanted to say.

Comment: If you need linearity, I suggest you to have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Reduction_to_a_second_order_linear_equation), explaining how to "rewrite" a Riccati equation to a linear second order differential equation.

Comment: I did not go through the problem thoroughly ... but if you choose $y=\coth\frac z 2$, then the equation simplifies to $z''-4=0$. I am not though still sure what you are after clearly ...

Comment: @Math-fun: nice substitution :-) I don't think I can use it, but I'm happy to see it. **mickep:** thank you.

Comment: why can't you use it? :-)

Comment: Because I have never seen those functions in course (but I know them anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are fine with
$$
f''=−2+2f^2+4xff'\text{ resp. } y''=−2+2y^2+4xyy'
$$
if there are no further requirement to the second order ODE. You could add multiples of the original ODE for variety, but that is not necessary.

Substituting the initial value for $f(0)=y(0)$ in the initial equation gives you $f'(0)=y'(0)$, inserting in this equation allows to compute $f''(0)=y''(0)$ and thus the required Taylor polynomial.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I in fact don't understand... :s What would be the linear ODE of second order ? To me $y''=-2+2y^2+4xyy'$ is not linear.

Comment: Please check again carefully your given problem statement if there is mention of "linear" in the first subtask. You don't want to borrow trouble where there is none. It may still be an interesting additional riddle to find or disprove the existence of a linear ODE for this function (which includes the whole solution family of the first order ODE, just for the IVP it would be trivial).

Comment: You right, it's not precise. Hummm... may be they don't ask the linearity... strange since we have never seen other differential equation  than linear ODE.

Comment: There is a problem, do you get $y''(0)=-\frac{3}{2}$ ? It's what I get, but the solution of the differential equation is $z(x)=\frac{3e^{2x^2}-1}{3e^{2x^2}-1}$, and $z''(0)=\frac{3}{2}$, what I'm I doing wrong ?? Thank you.

Comment: Obviously, $y'(0)=0$ and $y''(0)=-2+2y(0)^2=-\frac32$. If you started from the separation in the OP, then it is wrong, it has to be $(C)\ …=-2x$, this changed sign should then also account for the sign difference in the derivative.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. So the Taylor expansion is $y(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4}x^2+o(x^2)$ ? If yes, why when I solve the ODE, I get $y(x)=\frac{3e^{2x^2}-1}{3e^{2x^2}+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}x^2+o(x^2)$. Is it also correct ? If yes, why ? Thank you very much, and sorry for the disturbing.

Comment: Your solution starts (or at least should start) from $\frac{y'}{(1-y)(1+y)}=-2x$,  $\ln|1+y|-\ln|1-y|=-2x^2+C$, $\frac{1+y}{1-y}=Ce^{-2x^2}$, $C=3$, $y=\frac{3e^{-2x^2}-1}{3e^{-2x^2}+1}$, so you see that the initial sign difference carries through to the sign before $x^2$.

Comment: In fact my solution was false. Thank you for your precious help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\tanh \frac z 2$, then $$dy=\frac{dz}{1+\cosh z}$$ on the other hand $$(1+\cosh z) \left(1-\tanh ^2\frac{z}{2}\right)=2$$ therefore the equation $dy=-2x(1-y^2)dx$ becomes $$dz=-4xdx$$ or $$z''+4=0.$$